# How to catch value in a ComboBox just before SelectedValueChanged

Tags: vb.net, combobox, compact-framework

I work on VB.net Compact-framework (VS2008), I use a ComboBox, and I wish to have a function that get the previous `SelectedValue`, just before the `SelectedValue` changes to the new one (actually changes the `DisplayMember`).

Here is a generic example:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged
    Dim Bool As Boolean
    Bool = MyFunctionClose(ComboBox1.SelectedValueBeforeChange)
    ...
    Bool = MyFunctionOpen(ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
    ...
End Sub
```

My question is: Is it possible to catch such `ComboBox1.SelectedValueBeforeChange`?

Answer (score 1):

just store the `SelectedValue` in a variable on the event:

```
    Private cb1PrevValue as object = nothing

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged
        Dim Bool As Boolean
        If cb1PrevValue Is Nothing Then
            'cb1PrevValue = DEFAULT_VALUE (Give it a default value for when it is selected the first time)
        End If
        Bool = MyFunctionClose(cb1PrevValue)
        cb1PrevValue = ComboBox1.SelectedValue
        ...
        Bool = MyFunctionOpen(ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
        ...
    End Sub
```

Comment: I tend to use the Tag property of a control to store that kind of thing...makes for less clutter with class instance variables.

Comment: yes thats true... shame windows controls don't have like a collection of user set properties